# Disregard flags if the flagged post is already dealt with

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags

A lot of posts keep reappearing in the moderator queue a few minutes after they've been processed by a moderator.  This appears to be caused by users flagging <strike>from /review</strike> when they've had the page loaded for a few minutes.

I don't want to discourage anyone from flagging, so can we just disregard those flags with no penalty by suppressing posts from reappearing in the queue?  Of course this should only be if they're flagged for the *exact same* reason as the earlier processed flags, so moderators don't miss any "you made a mistake" flags.

Comment: Maybe this is only because there's a new flagging tool and there's a lot of flagging activity, but it's been like playing Whack-a-Mole today.

Comment: Except Whack-a-Mole is **fun**.

Comment: "correct me if I'm wrong": I don't know if this is going to be unique to flags from a stale `/review` or not.  When I'm reviewing I usually open each post I might be interested in from a page into it's own tab, then work through them.  So by the time I'm finished `/review` is probably stale, but I haven't been flagging from it, I've been flagging from the actual question/answer pages...  If this does get implemented, I'd prefer it if it was an across the board change, rather than just from the `/review` page...

Comment: @forsvarir: Thanks, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whack-a-Mole ... that is where all the fun is at!

I just added this to save us some pain and heartache.

[image]

Only happens in the `/tools/flagged' route if we happen to handle the flags before they submit the pile on flag.

Comment: You've got a typo: "handeled"

Comment: thanks for that catch !!! big oops